# Google Spreadsheet API (JSON) is redirecting Chrome users to the Google login page

Tags: json, api, google-chrome, spreadsheet

We are seeing a very strange issue with the Google Spreadsheet API.

We are using jQuery (JSONP) to fetch a document, like this:

```
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0At1XiR0Vfko3dFdKcEYwTHgwWVRmSHg0bUt6ck1qbVE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?'
$.getJSON(url, function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

The finished URL looks like this:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0At1XiR0Vfko3dFdKcEYwTHgwWVRmSHg0bUt6ck1qbVE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=jQuery18307236330607638174_1373548822356&_=1373548825543

Now the issue. In Chrome, visiting the above URL brings you to the Google Accounts login page instead of giving you the JSON API response.

This of course breaks the javascript code on the page since returned data is HTML instead of expected JSON.

Chrome error console displays:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I'm at a loss for words as to why this happens, and why it only affects Chrome. Any workarounds are welcome!

**Edit**: After further testing, this appears to occur when the Google Docs extension is installed in Chrome. Disabling the Google Docs extension solves the issue.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs/aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake

Comment: Odd. Just this morning I had *exactly* the same symptoms occurring for me, except for the following: 1) I don't have the Google Docs extension installed.  2) It was only happening to me when I was logged into Google Accounts as someone who had ownership of the spreadsheet in question.  ...when I logged in as a different user (personal email instead of work email), the issue went away.

Comment: ...aaand now I can't recreate the issue anymore.  Whether I'm logged in or not, or with coworkers accounts, it simply no longer occurs.  Perhaps it was a momentary hiccup?

Comment: We are no longer able to reproduce this, whether the GDocs extension is installed or not.At this point we can only speculate. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Opening Safari and deleting all cookies solved a similar issue for me. I was trying to download JSON in an Adobe AIR app, and HTML was being returned - the Google Docs login page. After the cookies were deleted, problem solved.

Comment: I experienced the same issue working with Adobe AIR app. and HTML. Tony's answer worked. for me. What's the connection with Safari's cookies and Adobe Air? I know they are both webkit engines but sharing the same cookies. Strange!